# Gradle "Could not open buildscript class cache" - is there a better way to resolve?

Tags: gradle

After adding a dependency to a .gradle file, our build server started having issues with the following being logged:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open buildscript class cache for build file '/u01/apps/.jenkins/workspace/[path name snipped]/build.gradle'     (/home/[username]/.gradle/caches/1.3/scripts/build_5jii90b0hvl37q9m8vfhik495b/ProjectScript/buildscript).
> java.io.EOFException
```

We were able to resolve it by clearing the gradle cache on the build slaves.  However, I'm concerned that this is just a temporary fix and it might show up again.  Is there a better way to fix this issue?

Comment: This looks similar to a bug I reported, http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2249. I haven't found any workaround better than deleting the cache on the CI server before building.

Comment: Thanks David, just now noticing someone responded on this thread.

Answer (score 28):

go to location ".gradle\caches\2.0\scripts\build_7l4t45nbnsvdcl79ol8u0beli4\ProjectScript" and remove 
cache.properties.lock file

Comment: Yey, that worked for me. What would a programmer do without the internet... ;-)

Comment: Keep deleting cache.properties.lock files in /ProjectScript/buildscript and /ProjectScript/no_buildscript, where ever it indicates. Worked for me after deleting 10 such files.

Comment: I am trying to delete this file it is saying 'The action can't be completed the file is open in java platform' .Even I kill the process in task manager processes.

Answer (score 13):

That exception typically occurs due to corrupted cache files.

Deleting the cache do work in most cases.

**Linux**

```
rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches
```

**Windows**

Delete the `%USER_HOME%.gradle/caches` folder

Answer (score 4):

First I would suggest you to upgrade from Gradle 1.3 to the latest version. The build script cache has changed a lot since 1.3.

Secondly, when running in a Jenkins environment, it is normally a good thing to consider moving gradle user home to another location than ~/.gradle/. It can be changed by setting the environment variable GRADLE_USER_HOME in Jenkins settings (configure system). In our environment for example, we have put the gradle cache on a local SSD disk instead of our NFS mounted ~/.

One third option is to use each jobs workspace as gradle user home. This is done by marking the checkbox "Force GRADLE_USER_HOME to use workspace" in the Jenkins job configuration. This is very effective if your jobs always run on the same machine and you don't remove the workspaces after each build.

Answer (score 3):

Running ./gradlew clean from the command line (within the project folder) seemed to clear it up for me.

Answer (score 2):

`C:\Users\John\.gradle\caches\2.4\scripts>del /S *.lock` did the trick for me using Win command prompt (there where a lot of .lock's). `rm` should do the same for Unix-like systems.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above works you can delete the caches folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this in Visual Studio 2015 after updating to Tools for Apache Cordova v7.

Just deleting the .lock files as above didn't help.

I also had to delete platforms folder. this folder is at the same level as your www folder (Not that VS adds it to .gitignore).

Then build, delete the .lock files, delete the entire cache_* folder, rinse, repeat until the build succeeds.